# remove duplicate value but keep rest of the row values in excel

Tags: excel

I have report for a project which needs to be filtered based on the first column. There  are several people working with same project on several dates.

```
ProjectName People  Dates
XYZ           KK    01/03/2014
XYZ           KY    02/03/2014
ABC           LL    03/03/2014
ABC           LY    04/03/2014
BBC           XY    05/03/2014
BBC           XY    06/03/2014
CBA           XX    07/03/2014
DBC           XX    08/03/2014
DDD           XX    09/03/2014
DDD           XY    10/03/2014
DDD           XX    11/03/2014
```

And the report I am looking should look  as below:

```
ProjectName      People    Date
XYZ            KK      01/03/2014
               KY      02/03/2014
ABC            LL      03/03/2014
               LY      04/03/2014
BBC            XY      05/03/2014
               XY      06/03/2014
CBA            XX      07/03/2014
DBC            XX      08/03/2014
DDD            XX      09/03/2014
               XY      10/03/2014
               XX      11/03/2014
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You could use a pivot table also.

Answer (score 1):

Give this tiny macro a try:

```
Sub luxation()
    Dim N As Long
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = N To 2 Step -1
        If Cells(i, 1) = Cells(i - 1, 1) Then
            Cells(i, 1) = ""
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: I have data as below  http://imageshack.com/a/img850/2900/mo5p.png h and want to remove duplicates from a column but want use the earliest date  avilable in other columns http://imageshack.com/a/img35/6807/twel.png

Answer (score 1):

**There is easy non VBA way:**

- **Step 1**

add formula `=A3=A2` in additional column in `D3` starting from the second row *of your data* (see picture below)

[image]

- **Step 2**

Select headers (range `A1:D1` in the picture below) and apply autofilter (go to  DATA->FILTER).

[image]

- **Step 3**

Filter out column `D` with criteria `=TRUE`

[image]

- **Step 4**

Select values in column `A`

[image]

- **Step 5**

With selected range press `Del`

[image]

- **Result**

Remove autofilter and temporary column `D`

[image]

Comment: Thanks.. It did work. cheers mate.. I am new user to stack overflow... Can I ask how did you manage to get the excel image?

Comment: Not sure I understood you correctly, but if you ask how to make screenshot of your excel, I used `PrtScr` key: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Print_screen

Comment: @user3313434, Or if you're asking how to upload it on SO, see this article: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28525/how-do-i-post-a-screenshot-on-stack-overflow